# QT connect a SIGNAL with fewer arguments than SLOT

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

I have this code:

```
QObject::connect(lineEdit_1, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), MainWindow, SLOT(myMethod(const QString &, QLineEdit* )) );
```

This code works correctly when *myMethod* has only the first argument (equal to the SIGNAL) but **I need to pass a pointer lo *lineEdit_1*** in order to allow *myMethod* to know on which LineEdit it has to operate.
What I should to do?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not necessary that you send as an additional argument the object that emits the signal for it, the [`QObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html)s have the [`sender()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) method that allows us to obtain that object:

```
QObject::connect(lineEdit_1, &QLineEdit::textChanged, MainWindow, &Your_Class::myMethod);
```

---

```
void Your_Class::MyMethod(const QString & text){
    if(QLineEdit *le = qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>(sender())){
        qDebug() << le;
    }
}
```

If you need to pass other arguments you can use the lambda functions but always take the time to see the limitations (how to use it depends on the context):

```
QObject::connect(lineEdit_1, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [ /* & or = */](const QString & text){
    MainWindow->MyMethod(text, another_arguments);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Anyway, how can I pass another argument? (it could be usefull)

Comment: note that sender() cannot be used in calls from different thread. On practice I've found that use of  lambda trick is very versatile and allows to dynamically create handlers with captured states for different widgets.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie a QObject should not be modified from another thread, lambdas are a good resource but you also have to be careful.

Comment: @eyllanesc there are legal ways..otherwise framework would limit to one  (barely two) threads which in modern terms might equal to use less than 5% of available resources. Note that Qt documentation doesn't say that scenario is illegal, it's just `sender()` got an inherent flaw. "You're doing this wrong" over time was replaced by "Not so wrong". :P

Comment: @eyllanesc There's a `connect` overload that accepts a second `QObject` as a "receiver". If you pass the actual receiver using that arg, Qt won't attempt to invoke the slot if the receiver has already been destroyed. If you're using multiple threads (and queued connections), also be sure to use `deleteLater` instead of just plain `delete` if you need to delete `receiver`.